# Differentiation Issue in Predictive Alignment for Attention Implementation

Tags: python, tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network, tf.keras

I am trying to implement local-p attention based on this paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1508.04025.pdf Specifically, equation (9) derives a alignment position based on taking the sigmoid of some non-linear functions, and then multiplying the resultant with number of timesteps. As sigmoid returns values between 0 and 1, this multiplication yields a valid index between 0 and number of timesteps. I can soft round this to infer the predicted position, however, I couldn't find a way to convert this to a integer to use within slicing/indexing operations since tf.cast() is not differentiable. Another problem is that the derived positions are in shape (B, 1), and hence one aligned position for each example in the batch. See below to understand these operations:

```
"""B = batch size, S = sequence length (num. timesteps), V = vocabulary size, H = number of hidden dimensions"""
class LocalAttention(Layer):
    def __init__(self, size, window_width=None, **kwargs):
        super(LocalAttention, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.size = size
        self.window_width = window_width # 2*D

    def build(self, input_shape): 
        self.W_p = Dense(units=input_shape[2], use_bias=False)
        self.W_p.build(input_shape=(None, None, input_shape[2])) # (B, 1, H)
        self._trainable_weights += self.W_p.trainable_weights

        self.v_p = Dense(units=1, use_bias=False)
        self.v_p.build(input_shape=(None, None, input_shape[2])) # (B, 1, H)
        self._trainable_weights += self.v_p.trainable_weights

        super(Attention, self).build(input_shape)

    def call(self, inputs):
        sequence_length = inputs.shape[1]
        ## Get h_t, the current (target) hidden state ##
        target_hidden_state = Lambda(function=lambda x: x[:, -1, :])(inputs) # (B, H)
        ## Get h_s, source hidden states ##
        aligned_position = self.W_p(target_hidden_state) # (B, H)
        aligned_position = Activation('tanh')(aligned_position) # (B, H)
        aligned_position = self.v_p(aligned_position) # (B, 1)
        aligned_position = Activation('sigmoid')(aligned_position) # (B, 1)
        aligned_position = aligned_position * sequence_length # (B, 1)
```

Let's say the `aligned_position` tensor has elements [24.2, 15.1, 12.3] for a batch size = B = 3 for simplification. Then, the source hidden states are derived from input hidden states (B=3, S, H) such that for the first example we take timesteps starting from 24, hence something along the lines of `first_batch_states = Lambda(function=lambda x: x[:, 24:, :])(inputs)` and so on. Note that the implementation of local-p attention is more complicated than this, but I simplified it here. Hence, the main challenge is converting 24.2 to 24 without losing differentiability, or using some sort of a mask operation to get the indexes through dot product. The mask operation is preferred, as we will have to do this for each example in batch, and having a loop inside a custom Keras layer is not neat. Do you have any ideas on how to accomplish this task? I will appreciate any answers and comments!

Comment: may i ask why don't you simply use  `equation-10` of the paper ? Will it not solve your issue of differentiability as this equation generates positions around `aligned_position` according to a gaussian.

Comment: The paragraphs above equation (9) indicate that the source hidden states are taken as the set [p_t - D, p_t + D]. I was looking for a slicing operation before the Gaussian step. I implemented the Gaussian step with a lambda function, and can now apply it to **all** hidden states and the results are pretty good. So thanks for your suggestion! Again, the Gaussian distribution solves the issue of differentiability, but this approach is still not equivalent to what the paper suggests as it applies the Gaussian step to the sliced version of source hidden states. At least in my understanding...

Comment: Could you solve your problem of slicing ?

Comment: Yes, but indirectly. I will add an answer below in case anyone is trying to do something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways I found to go about solving this problem.

- Applying a Gaussian distribution based on the aligned position shown in the original question to the attention weights, making the process differentiable, as @Siddhant suggested:

```
gaussian_estimation = lambda s: tf.exp(-tf.square(s - aligned_position) /
                                                   (2 * tf.square(self.window_width / 2)))
gaussian_factor = gaussian_estimation(0)
for i in range(1, sequence_length):
    gaussian_factor = Concatenate()([gaussian_factor, gaussian_estimation(i)])
# Adjust weights via gaussian_factor: (B, S*) to allow differentiability
attention_weights = attention_weights * gaussian_factor # (B, S*)
```

It should be noted that there is no hard slicing operation involved here, only simple adjusting according to distance.

- Keeping the top n values and zeroing out the rest as suggested by @Vlad here, [How to implement a custom keras layer that only keeps the top n values and zeros out all the rest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55650121/how-to-implement-a-custom-keras-layer-that-only-keeps-the-top-n-values-and-zeros):

```
aligned_position = self.W_p(inputs) # (B, S, H)
aligned_position = Activation('tanh')(aligned_position) # (B, S, H)
aligned_position = self.v_p(aligned_position) # (B, S, 1)
aligned_position = Activation('sigmoid')(aligned_position) # (B, S, 1)
## Only keep top D values out of the sigmoid activation, and zero-out the rest ##
aligned_position = tf.squeeze(aligned_position, axis=-1) # (B, S)
top_probabilities = tf.nn.top_k(input=aligned_position,
                                k=self.window_width,
                                sorted=False) # (values:(B, D), indices:(B, D))
onehot_vector = tf.one_hot(indices=top_probabilities.indices,
                           depth=sequence_length) # (B, D, S)
onehot_vector = tf.reduce_sum(onehot_vector, axis=1) # (B, S)
aligned_position = Multiply()([aligned_position, onehot_vector]) # (B, S)
aligned_position = tf.expand_dims(aligned_position, axis=-1) # (B, S, 1)
source_hidden_states = Multiply()([inputs, aligned_position]) # (B, S*=S(D), H)
## Scale back-to approximately original hidden state values ##
aligned_position += 1 # (B, S, 1)
source_hidden_states /= aligned_position # (B, S*=S(D), H)
```

It should be noted that here we are instead applying the dense layers to all hidden source states to get a shape of `(B,S,1)` instead of `(B,1)` for `aligned_position`. I believe this is as close as we can get to what the paper suggests.

Anybody who is trying to implement attention mechanisms can check my repo https://github.com/uzaymacar/attention-mechanisms. Layers here are designed for many-to-one sequence tasks, but can be adapted to other forms with minor tweaks.